# Google maps click on Point of interest returns different placeId on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps, google-places

I am working on react native application using package `"react-native-maps": "0.27.0"`. I am watching for click on Point of interest (poi) and trying to read a location returned object. But there is difference in `placeId` between IOS and Android.

Android response: `ChIJAAAAAAAAAAARE6VfRqb20Wo`

IOS response: `ChIJR-k4Ym_gPkcRE6VfRqb20Wo`

As you can see Android will replace big part of id with `AAAAAAAAAAA` rest of string is same.

Both platforms are set to use google maps (not apple maps).

Both IDs are valid, point to one POI and searchable but I am expecting `placeId` as unique and only one identifier for one location but it seems IOS and Android SDK has different sources. Is there any way how to use one identifier on all devices? Why is this happening?

Comment: A place id uniquely identifies a place. That doesn't mean that a place only has one id and according to the documentation, it can change at any time. I don't know why you get different IDs on the 2 platforms but as long as both are valid, I wouldn't consider this as a bug.

Comment: Yes, both are valid so I know this is not a bug, but there have to be some unique id for both platforms (maybe not available from maps api)

Comment: I can't tell. You could open a bug, even if it doesn't really feel like one, in the issue tracker and you might hopefully get a clear answer from Google. [iOSPlaces](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5050150) or [AndroidPlaces](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5466581) providing an example and linking to your question here. Maybe search in there first to see if this was already reported...

Comment: @Franky238 did you get any workaround. I am having same problem

Comment: @A.s.ALI did unify method where middle characters will be replaced by AAAAAAAAAAA. It is very dirty solution but working somehow

Comment: @Franky238 how it will work please elaborate